# How to create a mutlitype index in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

In several pages in Elasticsearch documentation is mentioned how to query a multi-type index.
But I failed to create one at the first place.

Here is my minimal example (on a Elasticsearch 6.x server):

```
PUT /myindex
{
  "settings" : {
    "number_of_shards" : 1
  }
}

PUT /myindex/people/123
{
  "first name": "John",
  "last name": "Doe"
}

PUT /myindex/dog/456
{
  "name": "Rex"
}
```

Index creation and fist insert did well, but at the dog type insert attempt:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "Rejecting mapping update to [myindex] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [people, dog]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason": "Rejecting mapping update to [myindex] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [people, dog]"
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

But this is exactly what I'm trying to do, buddy! Having "more than 1 type" in my index.

Do you know what I have to change in my calls to achieve this?

Many thanks.

Comment: Multiple mapping types are not supported from 6.0.0. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/breaking-changes-6.0.html

Comment: Simple and clear, thank you. I suggest you put it as an answer, for future searches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple mapping types are not supported from Elastic 6.0.0 onwards. See [breaking changes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/breaking-changes-6.0.html) for details.

You can still effectively use multiple types by implementing your own custom type field.

For example:

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "doc": {
            "properties": {
                "type": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
                "first_name": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "last_name": {
                    "type": "text"
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is described in [removal of types](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/removal-of-types.html).